# Number of Combinations to make change with coins

Tags: python-3.x

We have unlimited coins of different values - Calculate the unique combinations of how these coins can make up a specific amount. For example:

n = 4 (say, 4 cents)

coins_list = [1,2] - we have 1-cent coins, and 2-cent coins
The different combinations would be 112, 1111, and 22. (121 and 211 should be excluded since it's not unique - using one 2-cent coin and two 1-cent coin)

I have watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4y5Pr0YVhg
countless number of times, and edited my codes countless number of times, but I cannot manage to get rid of the same combination of different orders.

```
 def make_change(n, coinlist_index=None):
    coin_list = [1, 2]

    if coinlist_index == None: 
        coinlist_index = 0  
#coin index position in coin_list; starts at index 0 and cycles through all the coins

    if n == 0:
        return 1

    if n < 0:
        return 0

    ways = 0

    # if I use for i in range(len(coin_list)), it returns an error message saying that index is out of range
    for coinlist_index in range(len(coin_list)):
        ways += make_change((n - coin_list[coinlist_index]), coinlist_index)
        coinlist_index += 1

    return ways

make_change(4)
```

**Output:** 5

My output was 5 (different ways to make change for 4 cents with 1 and 2-cent coins), instead of 3 (which is what I want).

I'm sure it has to do with the for loop toward the end, but when i change "for coinlist_index in range..." to a different iterator, i, I get an error that says index is out of range.

What is going on, and more importantly, how can I fix it?

EDIT: P.S. This is just a simple example that I'm working through to solve the actual assignment - Which is with 6 types of coins, in cents, (1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100), and calculate how many ways to make change for 200 dollars. I have seen and tried the dynamic programming method out there, which worked, but we have to use recursion for assignment purposes.

Comment: The output of 5 is probably including 121 and 211 as possible combinations .. that's what's causing the discrepancy [bewteen the output and the desired output]

Comment: Consider storing the combinations as [`Sets`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), although memory may explode for high values of `n`.

Comment: @A.Far look at this [outline of permutations](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-all-the-permutation-of-a-list-in-python/)

Answer (score 0):

I feel 5 is actually the correct answer.

```
1 1 1 1
1 1 2
1 2 1
2 1 1
2 2
```

Or if you want distinct result, you may store results in the list and remove the duplicate result.

```
def make_change(n, coinlist_index=0):
    coin_list = [1, 2]

    if n == 0:
        return [[]]

    if n < 0:
        return []

    ways = []

    for coinlist_index in range(len(coin_list)):
        res = make_change((n - coin_list[coinlist_index]), coinlist_index)
        ways += list(map(lambda x : x + [coin_list[coinlist_index]], res))

    return ways

def remove_dup(lolist):
    res = []
    for lst in lolist:
        lst.sort()
        if lst not in res:
            res.append(lst)
    return res

print remove_dup(make_change(4))
```

Comment: 112 and 211(e.g) would not be considered "duplicates" as they are ordered differently

Comment: @RachelGallen It seems that OP does not mind about ordering, eg 112,211,121, all have just one 2 and 2 ones. So OP needs just one of them, without taking into account the ordering

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I got it working.  In each recursive pass you want to make sure that you aren't double counting possible ways to make the change.  My thought to do this was to make sure that you never go backwards in the coin_list.  So for the coin_list [1,2] if we ever use the 2 cent coin we never want the option to use the 1 cent coin afterwards.  I made sure it follows this order by changing your for loop a bit:

```
for i in range(len(coin_list)-coinlist_index):
    ways += make_change((n - coin_list[i+coinlist_index-1]), coinlist_index)
```

In the for loop I subtracted coinlist_index from the upper bound so we don't cycle over all coins once the index reaches 1, then added the index to where you pull from the coin_list, making sure once coinlist_index is 1 or more, we NEVER usecoin_list[0]. This got me to 3 in your sample case, hopefully it works for all cases.  Full code:

```
def make_change(n, coinlist_index=None):
    coin_list = [1, 2]

    if coinlist_index == None: 
        coinlist_index = 0  
#coin index position in coin_list; starts at index 0 and cycles through all the coins

    if n == 0:
        return 1

    if n < 0:
        return 0

    ways = 0

    # if I use for i in range(len(coin_list)), it returns an error message saying that index is out of range
    for i in range(len(coin_list)-coinlist_index):
        ways += make_change((n - coin_list[i+coinlist_index-1]), coinlist_index)
        coinlist_index += 1

    return ways

print(make_change(4))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! Your solution did work for this problem, but i doesn't work if there are more than 2 options of coins :(